# Changing LANG in Linux not giving desired results

Tags: linux

I am trying to execute a ksh script which extracts some details from Database in the form of a flat file. The issue here is that some of the characters in the data are in Arabic. I have set `LANG` in Linux to

```
LANG=ar_SA.utf8

-bash-4.2$ locale
LANG=ar_SA.utf8
```

However the Arabic characters are exported as `????` and not in Arabic.

Can you please advise if any other setup is missing?

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: can you paste the output of `$ locale` of your shell on terminal?

Comment: -bash-4.2$ locale
LANG=ar_SA.utf8
LC_CTYPE="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_TIME="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_PAPER="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_NAME="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ar_SA.utf8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Try adding shebang `#!/bin/bash /usr/bin/ksh --utf8` as first line of your ksh script

Comment: Thanks a lot will try and revert

Comment: HI Need help here when i am adding the shebang suggested I am getting the following error while running the script /bin/bash: /bin/ksh --utf8: No such file or directory. which sh and which bash as well as which ksh is showing correct path

Comment: -bash-4.2$ head -1 <script name> | od -c                                                                                              
0000000   #   !       /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h       /   b   i
0000020   n   /   k   s   h       -   -   u   t   f   8  \n
0000035